# Does Linq make it more expensive to upgrade my application at a later stage?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity

Is using Linq make it more expensive to maintain/upgrade my projects at a later stage?

Before I would have used stored procedures which are easy to modify after the code has gone to production.

I'm working for a customer who has legacy applications with lots of inline sql. They have paid to get these into stored procedures for applications where they require fast response times. And they are not excited by the prospect of using Linq seeing as it looks like inline sql to them as well.

Is Linq equivalent to inline sql? I know that Linq will make my life easier, but what about a year or two down the line?

Comment: Using linq with entity framework is slower. Anyways, EF also caches queries, so you might get a slower response the first time you access, but then they execute pretty quick. In the web there are few benchmarks comparing the performance. What I noticed, it that entity framework made db programming very easy. Maybe the time you gain using linq now is the time you lose maintaining it. I think ORM are really interesting. Maybe you have some slower responses time but you can develop app faster. This is the same that comparing records to a db manager system. The first is faster, but at what cost?

Comment: LINQ is better than inline SQL because it has type checking etc.

Comment: Also, writting stored procedures, views and all that can be painful if you need lots of them. The same with adding new data. With EF is just one line, in a database can take few more. If you modify a table, you must change your table object mapping in your c# app. EF does it automatically. Both ways are viable my friend. Some prefer using the db because they think is it more maintainable and reliable. I think a mature ORM can give you that too and more. Hope that helped

Comment: If you can choose, use Linq

Comment: Thanks Andres, I am using the Entity Framework which is not as mature as something like NHibernate. I think it might just come down to which is faster for the end-user, so stored procedures will still be faster no matter what? Is their a way to pre-cache and if this is done will it be faster?

Comment: You can always use SPROCs with Linq+EF to get faster results from the db. Sometiimes writing a complex linq query does not help that much and it is slower. SO using EF or ORM does not eliminate the need to use SPROCs or SQL queries at some point, but for sure it will be much less and clearer..

Comment: @codys-hole which version is it?

Comment: @codys-hole you can do that with [Compiled Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx)

Comment: Thanks guys its EF 5. @Flowerking I'll have a look at that...

Answer (score 2):

As long as the expression is more clear and easier to understand now, then I'm quite sure it will be easier to maintain in the future.

Comment: +1 Though the answer is quite simple.

Answer (score 2):

The only downside I've found to using Entity Framework is if you need to make an emergency change (let's say), you're looking at a code change instead of just modifying a stored procedure. For our environments, making a script change to a database is much easier than pushing out new code. So it somewhat comes down to which you'd prefer in your environment, pushing a new .dll, or pushing a stored procedure change.

As for maintainability, we've been using Entity Framework for quite some time and have had zero upgrade / maintainability issues. It's easy to write, easy to maintain, and if you write your Linq correctly, easy to update / change.

Comment: +1 - I take the point that sometimes rolling out a code change can be more painful than rolling out a sql change...

Answer (score 1):

In applications where everything is stored proc based, new functionality has to be both coded and scripted - which can be a pain to roll out.  With the newer way of doing things it can often be a case of exposing a new function using a different linq expression - the pain of creating new stored procs and upgrade scripts goes away.  (Of course the code still needs to be rolled out..)

The speed, in my opionion, is negligible - a stored proc will certainly be quicker and EF doesn't always come up with the best sql, but from it can make life simple:  if I have a middle/data tier for returning a customer by ID and I want to get a customer by name; I need a new method, new stored procedure, scripts to roll this out, etc.
Whereas using EF, I can just add a new method.